# Serving HTML files from Azure Blob for Express.js server

Tags: angularjs, node.js, azure, express, blob

So, I have an Express.js server and an Angular.js front end (Served through express itself and not deployed externally). We have multiple "themes" for the website which can be switched on the fly. Now the theme count is manageable, but we expect it to go into the thousands (maybe even ten thousands)

In the current implementation, we are storing the static theme files (HTML, CSS) in the deployment package itself. With the ever growing number of themes, the deployment package size is growing very quickly.

Now, I am considering moving the themes to an external storage (Azure Blob) and then stream the static content to Express.js from Azure Blob Storage and serve it accordingly.

Will Azure Blob Storage or any other storage be a bottleneck in this case? Or is there a better solution for this "theme" count problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blob storage is a good solution.
If you make the Bob storage public readable, then you can serve the static files directly from blob storage, they don't even have to come via your Express server, thus offloading all that. I often do this with css and have some apps where I serve the entire front end app, including scripts, from blob storage; I just have a single html page served from my main server with script tags pointing to blob storage.
With Angular 1 I just have a build step that bundles all the html templates inside the script package.

Later you can "upgrade" Bob storage to be a proper CDN, meaning you can have all the static stuff served locally to the user.

FWIW, I believe haveibeenpwned serves it's static content from Azure Blob storage.

Comment: What if the theme system is a little more dynamic? The main index html itself varies wildly between themes. For each theme, the CSS and some of the logic in Angular also varies. 

And we also need some leeway to allow users to edit a template and load up a version of it for themselves. Although a lot of our internal code on express already allows this, I'm just wondering if we'll be weighed down later.

Imagine hundreds(or even thousands) of "micro-sites" hosted on one express server. Each site will not get too many hits though.

Comment: That's more a matter of how you write your code. With Angular you can easily have a generic index.html and have everything visible in the script files.